# Background image html/css not changing

Tags: html, css

I just started getting into writing and I'm doing Dash's introduction to css.  I've been struggling to change the size of my background image for a website I am making.  The image does not change size or alignment.

Fixed.  Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>#Name</title>
    <style>
        body {
            text-align: center;
            background-size: 80%;
            background-position: center;
            background: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/13/Apollo_17_The_Last_Moon_Shot_Edit1.jpg") #Image that I am having a problem with.
        }
        h1 {
            color: white;
        }
        p {
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>#Name</h1>
    <p>#Description</p>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Your email here">
    <input type="submit">
</body>
```

Comment: place the `background-size` ***after*** the `background`, `background` will override everything related to background including `background-size`, `background-color`, `background-position`, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `background` attribute is shorthand for setting a bunch of settings, the second argument is the image url. You probably want `background-image` and it will work.
See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp) link

Answer (score 1):

Change `background` to `background-image`. The `background` is a shortcode and neutralizes every `background`-oriented style put earlier.

Answer (score 1):

declare auto for the height of the image, use `no-repeat` and also use `background-image`

```
body {
background-image: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/13/Apollo_17_The_Last_Moon_Shot_Edit1.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
text-align:center;
background-size: 80%;
background-position:center;   
}

h1 {
color:white;
}

p {
color:white;
}
```

check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oscarmosh/ad4ys/)